Clean way to check if variable is list of lists using pattern matching
In my code, I need to distinguish a list of records from a list of lists of records. The existing code does it like so:
if isinstance(input_var, list):
    if len(input_var) > 0:
        if all(isinstance(item) for item in input_var):
            return list_of_lists_processing(input_var)
        elif not any(instance(item, list) for item in input_var):
            return list_of_data_processing(input_var)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unexpected input_var value {input_var}")
    else:
        return list()
else:
    raise ValueError(f"Unexpected input_var value {input_var}")

However, this seems ugly. I want to use Python 3.10's pattern matching to simplify the code. I came up with this version:
match input_var:
    case [list(), *_]:
        return list_of_lists_processing(input_var)
    case list():
        # also process empty list case
        return list_of_data_processing(input_var)
    case _:
        ValueError(f"Unexpected value {input_var=}")

But there is a flaw here: case [*list(), *_] only checks the first element of input_var, not all of them. In practice, this is enough for my purposes, but I want to ask anyway: is there a clean way to match only a list where every element is a list?
I tried case [*list()]:, but this causes a SyntaxError. case list(list()): is syntactically correct, but doesn't work as expected (for example, it matches ["a"] - what is going on here?)

You can match the set of item types inside your list.
class Constants:
    set_of_list = {list}

match set(type(elem) for elem in input_var):
    case Constants.set_of_list:
        return list_of_lists_processing(input_var)
    case types if list in types:
        raise ValueError(f"Unexpected input_var value {input_var}")
    case _:
        return list_of_data_processing(input_var)

Python3.10 does not support matching values inside a set so you still have to check if list is one of the types.
The Constants class is used to trigger a value pattern. Raymond Hettinger made a great talk to explain this and other concepts related to pattern matching.

This is clever and beautiful; but it presupposes that we do have a sequence, and can't (as far as I can tell) be adapted to short-circuit with any/all

Looks like there is no "real" clean way to check for list of list with pattern matching, but IMO this is close; and thanks for the youtube link, great talk!

There isn't a straightforward way to directly match a list where the elements are lists. So, you can combine pattern matching with a guard clause.
Try this:
match input_var:
        # matches lists of lists using a guard clause
    case [first_list, *rest_lists] if all(isinstance(item, list) for item in [first_list] + rest_lists):
        return list_of_lists_processing(input_var)
    case list():
        # also process empty list case
        return list_of_data_processing(input_var)
        # handle other unexpected values 
    case _:
        raise ValueError(f"Unexpected value {input_var}")


It doesn't seem necessary to "peel off" the first_list from the rest_lists since nothing else will treat it specially. This would make more sense if the goal were to ensure all the elements are the same type, but not necessarily a specific type.

Apparently I can't offer the additional smaller bounties that I wanted to. Unfortunately you and TMBailey will have to settle for my upvote. Good job, at any rate.

If you are open to a solution without match case you can use set to check if all the values in input_var are of the same type (all records or all lists)
if isinstance(input_var, list) and len(types := {type(i) for i in input_var}) <= 1:
    if list in types:
        return list_of_lists_processing(input_var)
    return list_of_data_processing(input_var)
raise ValueError(f'Unexpected input_var value {input_var}')

An empty list will be processed by list_of_data_processing as in your question.

This is very inefficient as you get the type of all items in the list whether it's a list or not. The construct with all  returns False as soon as it finds a non list item.

Solving the problem in other ways is useful, but I'm sure there must be some other question about it. (If the problem is specifically "check whether all elements of a sequence have the same type", I'm quite confident I've seen that before.) By offering the bounty I really hoped to explore the match-case paradigm for OP's problem. That said, a solution like this can certainly be adapted to use the all approach and benefit from the short-circuiting, too.

We can build on the approach of @DrJay, with some minor improvements and providing some test data.
## Some test data    
ldata = [10, 20, 30]  # list of records

list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [3, 4, 5]
llist = [list1, list2]  # list of lists

# Toy processing for a list of lists
def list_of_lists_processing(x):
    """Return list or processed lists"""
    return [f"processed_list({item})" for item in x]

# Toy processing for a list of data
def list_of_data_processing(x):
    """Return list of processed data"""
    return [f"processed_data({item})" for item in x]

def process_list(input_var):
    """Return processed list of lists or list of data"""
    match input_var:
        case [*items] if not any(isinstance(item, list) for item in items):
            # Process list of records (or empty list).
            return list_of_data_processing(input_var)
        case [*items] if all(isinstance(item, list) for item in items):
            # Process list of lists.
            return list_of_lists_processing(input_var)
        case _:
            raise ValueError(f"Unexpected value {input_var}")

List of records:
process_list(ldata)
# ['processed_data(10)', 'processed_data(20)', 'processed_data(30)']

List of lists:
process_list(llist)
# ['processed_list([1, 2])', 'processed_list([3, 4, 5])']

Empty list:
process_list([])
# []


This is a nice elaboration, though a bit beyond the scope of what was asked for.

Apparently I can't offer the additional smaller bounties that I wanted to. Unfortunately you and DrJay will have to settle for my upvote. Good job, at any rate.

I match the builtin class as list(x) which matches only a list and the positional parameter x binds to the matched list.
And I guard the pattern for list of lists with all which returns False as soon as it finds a non-list item in the_list, very efficient compared to some set based solution.
match l:
    # case list(the_list) if the_list and all(isinstance(item, list) for item in the_list):
    case list(the_list) if the_list and all(type(item) is list for item in the_list):
        print('lol')
        print(the_list)
    case list(the_list):
        print('list')
        print(the_list)
    case _:
        print('no')

Test;
l = [0, 1, 2]
l = [[2], [3], [4]]
l = []

Output;
list
[0, 1, 2]

lol
[[2], [3], [4]]

list
[]

To match a sequence like list, tuple or range object;
from collections.abc import Sequence

match l:
    case *the_list, if the_list and all(isinstance(item, Sequence) for item in the_list):
        print('lol')
        print(the_list)
    case *the_list,:
        print('list')
        print(the_list)
    case _:
        print('no')


@Guy Please refer to PEP 636 matching builtin classes, in case statement, list(the_list) does not iterate over all items in the_list, but only checks whether the_list is an instance of the list.

@MechanicPig that's why I guard the pattern with all.

After careful consideration, I like this one best. I'm in a generous mood and may award additional bounties later. It's worth noting that matching list(the_list) requires that the input is actually specifically a list. This may or may not be desirable. Matching [*the_list] also accepts tuples and range objects, and possibly some other kinds of sequences (but, notably, not strings or generators).

@KarlKnechtel Updated to match sequences.

Consider this refactoring where you sum all list instances of items in list with special handling of non-list or empty list. Original logic was unclear how you want to handle lists of non-list items. Below sets up a zero condition if needed to separate from default.
islists = (
    [isinstance(x, list) for x in input_var] 
    if isinstance(input_var, list) and input_var != list() 
    else [-99]
)

class Vals:
    all = len(input_var)
    null = -99
    zero = 0
  
match sum(islists):
    case Vals.all:
        # ALL ITEMS OF INPUT LIST ARE LIST TYPES
        return list_of_lists_processing(input_var)
    case Vals.null:
        # INPUT LIST IS NOT A LIST OR IS EMPTY
        ValueError(f"Unexpected value {input_var=}")
    case Vals.zero:
        # NO ITEM IN INPUT LIST IS A LIST TYPE
        return list_of_data_processing(input_var)
    case _:
        # AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN INPUT LIST IS A NON-LIST TYPE
        return list_of_data_processing(input_var)


Arithmetic hacks like this definitely don't seem desirable.
